# Cross-domain SSL handshake failure in Firefox using xhr, client-certificate

Tags: javascript, ajax, firefox, https, client-certificates

The setup is as follows:

- Firefox (both 3.x and 4b) with properly set up and working certificates, including a client certificate.
- Web page with an XMLHttpRequest() type of AJAX call to a **different subdomain**.
- Custom web server in said subdomain accepting requests, reponding with a permissive `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header and **requiring client verification**.

The problem is that Firefox aborts the request (well, that's what it says in firebug anyway) abruptly.  Running the setup with `openssl s_server` instead hints that Firefox actually doesn't even send the client certificate:

```
140727260153512:error:140890C7:SSL routines:SSL3_GET_CLIENT_CERTIFICATE:peer
did not return a certificate:s3_srvr.c:2965:ACCEPT
```

The same exact setup works perfectly with Chrome, suggesting perhaps a bug in Firefox. **However, performing the ajax call with a `<script>` element injected into the DOM seems to work as intended...**

So, has anyone else run into this? Is it a bug? Any workarounds? Is there something obvious missing?

Comment: A workaround could be to use the opensource Forge project: https://github.com/digitalbazaar/forge/blob/master/README

Comment: Cheers for input. Forge seems pretty neat project, but since it requires Flash it is not applicable here.

Comment: As an update, I found [this Mozilla article](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/http_access_control) and tried the scenario with a "preflighted" request. Which also fails in a similar fashion.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

*Chiming in 5 years later probably isn't much help to the OP, but in case someone else has this issue in the future...*

Firefox appears to **not** send the client certificate with a cross-origin XHR request by default. Setting `withCredentials=true` on the XHR instance resolved the issue for me. Note that I also did not see this problem with Chrome--only Firefox.

For more info see [this Mozilla Dev Network blog post](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS#Requests_with_credentials). In particular, the following statement:

> By default, in cross-site XMLHttpRequest invocations, browsers will
>   not send credentials. A specific flag has to be set on the XMLHttpRequest object when it is invoked.

Answer (score 3):

The reason injecting the script works as opposed to a simple XHR request is because of the [Single Origin Policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy). This would probably explain why Chrome allows the XHR but not FF; Chrome considers the subdomain part of the same origin, but FF does not.

Injecting scripts from other domains (which is what Google Analytics does) is allowed and one of the practices to handle this situation.

The way my team handles this situation is by making a request through a server-side proxy.

I would recommend using a server-side proxy if you can, but the script injection method works fine as long as the code is coming from a trusted source.

I also found [this article](http://fettig.net/weblog/2005/11/28/how-to-make-xmlhttprequest-connections-to-another-server-in-your-domain/) which describes your situation.

Comment: What about the [Access-Control-Allow-Origin](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/HTTP_access_control) HTTP header? Can't verify it now, but iirc even Chrome failed without it, and isn't it supposed to handle cross domain trust issues like this? Firefox allegedly supports it from 3.5 onwards.

Comment: +1 for contributing though :) Server side proxies and other workarounds would be possible, but looking for the least-components-involved solution. Imho this is something that should be possible in 2010...

Comment: thanks for the link and upvote! This is a great read as I am a novice with the new Cross-site requests.  It may in fact be a bug since this code is still fairly new and may not have been stress tested a lot.  I would search FF's bug tracker or hop on their IRC channel to confirm the bug. If so - great find!

Comment: five years later... :\  --- solved it by encoding my script as base64 and placing it in src of the page instead of using xhr, the script injects an iframe with the url "about:blank" and then *writes* a plain html5 src to create a document (it is policy-less) the iframe is like a proxy :)) inception, used this trick in several top-10 companies products.